# My directive is not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to recreate `nsClick` behavior with my directive ( changing priority).
So this is my code:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('nsClickHack', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    priority: 100,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        key: '=',
        value: '=',
        accept: "&"
    },
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
        $scope.method();
    }
}
});
```

and the line I'm trying to bind to:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ns-click-hack="toggle(); item.action()">
```

`toggle` and `item.action` are from other directives.

Can you point me where I was making mistake?

Comment: Your directive is set to `restrict: 'E'`, but you are using it as an attribute. Set it to `restrict: 'A'` or `'EA'`. Also, you are not actually doing with the value assigned to the `ns-click-hack` attribute. Did you intend for it to be a callback function? And it's not at all clear what `$scope.method` is.

Comment: It was effect of combining of multiple questions from this page. Unfortunatelly in angular docs I found no suggestions how to resolve my issue

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "it"? Just, edit your question to clarify'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to re-create `ng-click`, then it's probably better to look at the [source of the `ngClick` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.13/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L52).

For example, it does not create an isolate scope since only one isolate scope can be created on an element and it tries to be accommodating towards other directives. The alternative is to `$parse` the attribute value, which is what the built-in implementation is doing.

If you are just creating a "poor's man" version of `ngClick`, then, sure, you could use a callback function `"&"` defined on the scope, and invoke it when the element is clicked:

```
.directive("nsClickHack", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      clickCb: "&nsClickHack"
    },
    link: function(scope, element){
      element.on("click", function(e){
        scope.clickCb({$event: e}); // ngClick also passes the $event var
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The usage is as you seem to want it:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ns-click-hack="toggle(); item.action()">
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VCtoRRhb0uDsDvZFlbkP?p=preview)